# Script to automate browser visitng a URL action and its logging action

Tags: browser, script

I want to do something as below.
There is a website on our office intranet network. It is based in one LAN segment of our office in other location different from where I am based. We are facing the problem due to some VPN issues in accessing this site. For logging purposes to get to the cause of this:

I want to visit this site periodically thorughout the day and find out, when it is accessible(it does work at times) and when it was not reachable(due to our VPN errors)

How can I write a Script to continuously visit this site URL using web browser(mozilla say) after fixed intervals of time and log the result of this action in a text file with time stamp when the browser tried to access this site, if successful or Error Page not found.

Answer (score 0):

Using Autoit, this is a simple test that will run once every 10 seconds to see if the target page source is accessible, it will log the result with a timestamp:

```
#include <inet.au3>

While 1
    $source = _InetGetSource("domain.tld")
    $file = FileOpen("log.log", 9)
    If $source = "" Then
        FileWrite($file,@MON & "/" & @MDAY & "/" & StringRight(@YEAR, 2) & " " & @HOUR & ":" & @MIN & ":" & @SEC & @TAB & "Failed source pull" & @CRLF)
    Else
        FileWrite($file,@MON & "/" & @MDAY & "/" & StringRight(@YEAR, 2) & " " & @HOUR & ":" & @MIN & ":" & @SEC & @TAB & "Successful source pull" & @CRLF)
    EndIf
    FileClose($file)
    Sleep(10000)
WEnd
```